# angular material Could not find column

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following code but I get this error for no reason:

> ERROR Error: Could not find column with id "continent".

I already added the display column part so I am not sure why I am getting this error.

```
   <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
   <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="continentName">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>continentName </mat- 
    header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let country"> {{country.continentName}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="countryName">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>countryName </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let country"> {{country.countryName}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="areaInSqKm">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>areaInSqKm </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let country"> {{country.areaInSqKm}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="population">
                  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>population </mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let country"> {{country.population}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>


    @Component({
   selector: "app-root",
   templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
   styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
   })
   export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   title = "my-case-study";
   displayedColumns = 
   ['continentName','countryName','areaInSqKm','population'];
   dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);
```

Comment: Can you share the code where the error is thrown?

Comment: On this line  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

Comment: Ah, I must be blind. I'm not super familiar with this iteration of Angular, so I just wanted to check if it was just a spelling issue.

Answer (score 1):

you forget th and td "mat-header" and "mat-cell" are directives of "th" and "td"
e.g.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="continentName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>continentName </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let country"> {{country.continentName}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

You only write

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="continentName">
   <!--here missing "th"-->
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>continentName </mat- 
header-cell>
  <!--here missing td-->
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let country"> {{country.continentName}} </mat-cell>
```

Comment: not ture. i am not missing th and td. check this exmaple : https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/

Comment: see that in the link use "div", `*matHeaderCellDef` is -see the `*`- a "structural directive" https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#what-are-structural-directives, they need applied to a "html tag"